# How to bind model after method call in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm calling this following method and assign to a variable for binding in HTML. But, it doesn't work. May be for Async.

**Calling the method:**

```
$scope.Parity.TofProvidingElectrolite = $scope.ConvertDateTimeToUTCFormat($scope.Parity.TofProvidingElectrolite);
```

**Method:**

```
$scope.ConvertDateTimeToUTCFormat = function (val) {

        $scope.dateTimeString = null;

        if (val !== null) {
            var fields = val.split('-').join(',').split('T').join(',').split(':').join(',').split(',');

            var year = fields[0];
            var month = fields[1];
            var day = fields[2];
            var hr = fields[3];
            var min = fields[4];

            $scope.dateTimeString = new Date(year, month, day, hr, min, 0);

            return $scope.dateTimeString;
        }

        return $scope.dateTimeString;

    };
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input kendo-time-picker k-date-input="true" k-ng-model="Parity.TofCalfBorn" />
                                    {{Parity.TofCalfBorn}}
```

**This works fine:**

```
$scope.testInput = new Date(2019, 08, 06, 06, 04, 0);
```

Comment: Only tag as Angular for Angular 2+

Comment: Try [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).